# In a nested set of logic apps,Is it possible to bubble errors up?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

We have a parent logic app that calls child logic apps, which in turn can call other child logic apps depending on the scenario.
The parent logic app is really just for orchestration.

Occasionally, one nested/child logic app will fail, but the parent logic app will show as succeeded.
Is it possible to bubble errors up to the parent logic app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I can think of is to build you Child logic apps with a HTTP Request trigger. The parent calls it and expects a result. When you Child has an issue, return the error and a response code, say 500 (forcefully fail the child), then the Parent can parse the response to check what the response code is. If it's 500, then you can do whatever you want with that error then forcefully fail the Parent.